# Defining functions that gives min, max and average from an input text file (Python)

Tags: python, list, function, max, min

I am trying to define a function that can give me these outputs below when i run any length or combination of integers through it.
so this is the question i have been given:

write Python code to read in the input of the textfile 'input.txt', and for each line in input.txt, write out a new line in a new text file output.txt that computes the answer to some operation on a list of numbers.

```
If the input.txt file has the following:

min: 1,2,3,5,6
max: 1,2,3,5,6
avg: 1,2,3,5,6

Your program should generate an output.txt file as following:

The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4
```

This is my code so far:

```
textFile = open('input.txt', 'r+')
numberList = []
for line in textFile:
    numberList.append(line.split(','))
for e in numberList:
    print e
textFile.close()

def minimum(mi):
    minimun = min(numberList)
    return minumum

def maximum(ma):
    maximum = max(numberList)
    return maximum

print minimum(numberList)
print maximum(numberList)
```

there is a problem when i try to call my function and i'm not sure if the function has been defined wrong or if i am calling it wrong.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also post the error or nature of the problem that you're getting?

Comment: ok i was getting the error because i miss pelt minimum. but instead of my desired answer i get this in the output: <function minimum at 0x02AAF830>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your functions are no using the supplied argument which you would expect, and secondly you are shadowing the name of your function with your local argument.

You can simplify your functions like so

```
def minimum(mi):
    return min(mi)
```

Or if you want to store the result locally for whatever reason then do so in a variable with a different name to your function like so

```
def minimum(mi):
    min_value = min(mi)
    return min_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't name your `variable`s with the names of `function`s, so you should change this:

```
def maximum(ma):
    maximum = max(numberList)
    return maximum
```

to for example:

```
def maximum():   # mind that arg ``ma`` is spare since you don't use it at all
    my_maximum = max(numberList)
    return my_maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code.

```
def minimum(mi):
    minimun = min(numberList)
    return minumum
```

1. You are taking input of `mi` but using `numberList`, which is confusing and potentially buggy (though it happens to work in this example because the function will reach out to get the global `numberList`).
2. Your return variable is the same name as your function, while the variable you use for `min(numberList)` is `minimun`
3. In fact there's no reason for you to create these functions, as they do exactly the same thing as the built-in `min`/`max` functions.
4. Your numList is being created as a list of strings (including strings like 'min: 1', '2' etc).  You probably want to convert the numerical values using `int(x)`
5. You probably want to first split off the first section in each line, that says 'min: ', 'max: ', 'avg: ' etc, using something like `line.split(': ')`.  Your input to `max`, `min` etc should be whatever follows that section, split and converted into integers.